# FIT-like testing in the .Net world

Tags: c#, .net, testing, fitnesse

I managed to get FIT up and running using fixtures implemented in C#. I really like the concept, but the infrastructure does not fit in my environment. FIT and source code management do not work together easily and having a Java server up and running to execute the tests is also not very nice.

Does anybody know similar tools which are better integrated into the .Net world?

Comment: Assuming you are using FitSharp (http://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp) already.  There is guidance on SO for handling sourcecode and FitNesse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249580/how-do-i-add-fitnesse-pages-to-version-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/) does a similar job in a different way, and there's also Cucumber for .Net - [Cuke4Nuke](http://wiki.github.com/richardlawrence/Cuke4Nuke/) (although this can be a little tricky to get running as it uses Ruby).

Comment: SpecFlow seems to be the best choice. I like that it's based on proven technology like NUnit, ...

Answer (score 2):

[Storyteller](http://storyteller.tigris.org/) by Jeremy D. Miller.

I think this has moved to http://storyteller.github.io/, but I am leaving the old link in the answer as it may be a different project.

Comment: Very interesting project that I'd never heard of before.  Very professional looking site (the GitHub one), they've obviously spent a fair bit of time on it.  And the site mentions StoryTeller works with .NET Core so it's obviously under active development in 2016-17.  It looks to me similar to Robot Framework but without the hassle of having to write test code in Python.

Comment: BTW, it does look like the same project in the Tigris and GitHub links.  Jeremy Miller turns up in the forum posts on the GitHub site.

Answer (score 2):

And I hear [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/) should work too.